# PHC Configure fails. Can't find boost library but it's installed

Tags: php, build, compilation

For some reason when I attempt to configure phc-0.2.0.3 oh my machine (Fedora Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.34.6-47.fc13.i686 #1 SMP Fri Aug 27 09:48:44 UTC 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux) I get the following error:

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.34.0... configure: error: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.34 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
```

Boost is installed to /usr/include/boost.  I tried setting the environment variable as specified in the error to $BOOST_ROOT=/usr/include/boost and when that didn't work i tried $BOOST_ROOT=/usr/include.  Once I did that I tried

```
./configure --with-boost
```

and

```
./configure
```

Both times I got the same error.  Here is the site for phc:
http://www.phpcompiler.org/

The boost site is here:
http://www.randspringer.de/boost/ucl.html

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: `If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>` - did you do that?

Comment: I did;
#define BOOST_VERSION 104100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recompiled PHP and installed it.  That resolved the issue.